# density in my texture atlas?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, texture-coordinates

I would like to know how can I get better results of my atlas and my performance.

The questions are at the final of this thread in 6-7 "*"....

*1 - first of all I ve created my texture atlas with this 4 assets.

[image]

*2 - consider I am using a checker pattern for see the pixel density ? ( I ve made square as possible to avoid the stretching? and try to make all the same size as possible using "average island scale"  , the pixel bleeding of 16 px , and margin of 0.006 per island )

[image]

*3- If I want more detail in some area , I should scale an island  and applyed average scale just to ensure  . for example I wanto to have more resolution in this area, (the front of this house)
[image]

*4- so in "blender" the atlas is 2048x2048 (I painted in blender with gradient bucket and then export to unity , see the results in "unity" , it is a mess , I ve checked "swap uv" in inspector...however , see it is very blurred..)
[image]

*5 - If I increase the resolution it is logic, I will have better result...but I need to keep very low for my game and my target , it is for mobile's game.
[image]

*6 - mmm finally I think ... should I make a better organization in my texture atlas? are there many objects in the UV's texture space  m 4 assets in 1 texture atlas?  If my optimal size of resolution is 2048x 2048 in "PNG" compress format...why the blurred?? when the object is build up in code the shader reads the portion of the Uv's island  for the respective object and refresh everytime in the screen...

*7 - I use for this texture atlas "unwrap -> smart uv" ( I ve not created any mark seams (control +e) for this case.... I used "smart uv" for 90 degree angles , in some cases as the front of every house I use "project from view" ... I ve scaled portions of the UV that I consider interesting to get more resolution and better results, for example the door or the first floor of the house. but I do not know why is so blurred, the UV's are ok. the 80% of the UV space are blue and covered with the whole assests ...

Comment: If it looks clear in Blender but blurred in Unity, I suspect it's a problem with settings in Unity. I just searched online "unity texture looks blurred" and all sorts of results came up. You might look into that first before examining your .blend.

Comment: I used to load the models in a empty project in unity , different for my original game's model and then , in that project I used to check the texture, resolution and all the things ...uv swap, anti-aliasing if it would be necessary... and with a gradient map I should not have any problems...but blurred effects appears in the edge ...I use pixel bleeding too...similar to edge padding...don't know about this problem..